# rearrange a queue of integers

Tags: java, stack, queue

I trying to write a method that can rearrange a queue of integers from even to odd.

such that  [3, 5, 4, 17, 6, 83, 1, 84, 16, 37]  will be like  [4, 6, 84, 16, 3, 5, 17, 83, 1, 37]

but im kinda stuck right now, can someone pls help me. Here is what I got so far

```
public void rearrange(Queue<Integer> q) {
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
    int size = q.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int n = q.remove();
    if (n % 2 == 1 || n % 2 == -1) {
        q.add(n);
    } 

    if( n % 2 == 0) {
        q.add(n);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think your approach can be made to work; rather than using a single helper stack, I think you need to use two helper queues (one to hold the even values, one to hold the odd ones).

Comment: Addendum/correction: since you check your queue size beforehand, and iterate based on that rather than based on whether the queue is non-empty, you can use the queue itself as one of the "helper queues" I referred to in my previous comment. And using that approach, you could replace the other helper queue with a stack, provided you're willing to run your whole operation twice (so that the elements end up in the right order). So, you actually *can* do this with just a helper stack, if you want: it's just a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort is okay, but it takes O(n log n) time, when you can do this in O(n) pretty easily.  I think this is what Evgeniy Dorofeev also proposed:

```
public static void rearrange(Queue<Integer> q) {
    Queue<Integer> tmp = new LinkedList<>();

    // Remember size and rearrange that many items.
    int size = q.size();

    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
        Integer head = q.poll();

        // Even items go on the end of the original queue, odd to temp.
        (head % 2 == 0 ? q : tmp).offer(head);
    }
    // Glue temp queue of odd values onto original which is all even.
    q.addAll(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has `Comparator` for exactly this sort of thing.  Put them in a `java.util.List`.  Write a comparator, something like:

```
class OddEvenComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
  public int compare (Integer a, Integer b) {
    boolean aOdd = (a % 2) != 0;
    boolean bOdd = (b % 2) != 0;
    return aOdd == bOdd ? a.compareTo(b) : aOdd ? -1 : 1;
  }
}
```

so that

- If they are both odd or even, they are compared on value
- If a is odd and b is not, its position shifts backward
- If a is even and b is not, its position shifts forward

use `Collections.sort(theList, new OddEvenComparator())` to sort.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp queue (or a list). Iterate over the main queue removing odd elements and placing them to the temp queue. Finally addAll list elements to the main queue